# can anyone explain this peudo code (partition)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

1.can anyone please explain and read this code? this is Searching K-th key Pseudo code, It seems not difficult, but I am having a difficulty in understanding those lines of code. Especially, I want you to share how you approach in partition(), I understand reclusive function works, so you don't have to explain selection function, but if you want to, you can do that.. ( This is my first question and please tell me if my question is ambiguous. )

```
 keytype selection(index low, index high, index k) {
     index pivotpoint;
     if(low == high)
       return s[low];
     else {
         partition(low, high, pivotpoint);
         if (k == pivotpoint)
           return s[pivotpoint];
         else if (k < pivotpoint)
           return selection(low, pivotpoint-1, k);
         else 
           return selection(pivotpoint+1, high, k-pivotpoint);
         }
   }    

 void partition(index low, index high, index& pivotpoint) { 
     index i,j;
     keytype pivotitem;
     pivotitem = s[low];
     j=low;
     for (i = low+1; i <= high; i++)
      if(s[i] < pivotitem) {
       j++;
       exchange s[i] and s[j];
      }
     pivotpoint = j;
     exchange s[low] and s[pivotpoint];
    }
```

Comment: What precisely do you not understand?

Comment: Maybe a visualization of quicksort would help you

Comment: Get a book. https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm.

The idea of `partition` is to partition elements in the array `s` between `low` and `high` as follows:

- It first picks a `pivotitem`, in this case it's `s[low]`.
- It loops through `s` (starting from `i=low+1`) and moves all elements that are less than `pivotitem` to the left part of the array (also starting from `j=low+1`).
- When the loop terminates, `s[low+1,...,j]` are all less than `pivotitem`, and `s[j+1,...,high]` are all greater than or equal to `pivotitem`.
- The last two lines point `pivotpoint` to `j`, and move `pivotitem` to that position.

To summarize, when the function terminates, the variable `pivotpoint` points to a position between `low` and `high`, **and** all elements between `low` and `pivotpoint-1` are less than `s[pivotpoint]` and all elements between `pivotpoint+1` and `high` are greater than or equal to `s[pivotpoint]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are selecting a pivot element. After partitioning, all the elements smaller than pivot element will be on left side of pivot and all the elements greater than the pivot will be on right side. You can select any element as pivot element.
Once the pivot element is chosen, you first assign an initial position to pivot element which is low in your case. Then we loop through all the elements and see if they are smaller or greater than pivot element. Now two case arises:

1. When a[i] > pivot: As (i > j) always hold true, the array element is already on the right side of pivot element.
2. When a[i] < pivot:In this case, the array element lies on right side of pivot and is smaller than pivot. So, we should shift it to left side of pivot. So, we increase the position of pivot element by 1 and move the smaller element to pivot position and greater element to the right side.
   At last after iteration, we push the value of pivot element to its position.

For further reference, refer to [quick sort](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COk73cpQbFQ).